# Rotate edge loop in oval cylinder object

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

Hi, everyone. I have a problem with an oval cylinder object. How can I rotate the horizontal edges (highlighted in image) without ruining the shape of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the loop of faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->***Rotate CW*** or ***CWW***.

[image]

Comment: oh thks... very usefull method

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the vertex slide tool  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd> .

[image: Vertex slide]

Put in mind that it is mouse cursor based so move the pointer to get what you want.

Comment: i was use this method. but, side vertex is crash